# PS/2 Keyboard via serial port

Tags: keyboard, serial-port

I'm trying to connect a PS/2 keyboard to a SuperMicro X7DBT-INF via its serial port and an [adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HGI5JPA).  I've tried using the 
[inputattach](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/inputattach.1.html) package, but this is really my first time working with serial and I haven't been able to make any headway, and their man page doesn't offer much for the uninitiated.

I've tried `inputattach --daemon -ps2ser /dev/ttyS0` to no success.  I've also tried manually setting the baud rate `input attach --daemon --baud 115200 -ps2ser /dev/ttyS0` but it returns an invalid baud rate error (this is the base_baud I get from `dmesg | grep tty`)

Any suggestions of what to try?  Or is it time to return those adapters and leave my home lab console with one keyboard for USB and another for PS/2?

Answer (score 0):

Note your computer-on-a-board has a: **Fast UART 16550 serial port**

From: [Serial HOWTO](ftp://ftp.wayne.edu/ldp/en/Serial-HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO.pdf)

### 5.6 Standard PC Serial Cards

In olden days, PCs came with a serial card installed. Later on, the serial function was put on the hard-drive
interface card. In the 1990s and early 2000s one or two serial ports were usually built into the motherboard
(on-board). Most of them (as of 2002) use a 16550 but some use 16650 (32-byte FIFOs). But one may still
buy the individual PC serial cards if they need more serial ports. They can be used to connect external serial
devices (modems, serial mice, etc...). Only a tiny percentage of retail computer stores carry such cards. But
one can purchase them on the Internet. Before getting one for the PCI bus, make sure Linux supports it.
Here's a list of a few popular brands:

- Byte Runner (may order directly, shows prices) http://www.byterunner.com
  •
- SIIG http://www.siig.com/products/io/
  •
- Dolphin http://www.dolphinfast.com/sersol.html
  •

Note: due to address conflicts, you may not be able to use `/dev/ttyS3` with a IBM8514 video card (and some
others) simultaneously. See Avoiding IO Address Conflicts with Certain Video Boards